# WPF ToolBarControl in multiple UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm working on a project where the request is to implement `ToolBarControl` in multiple `UserControls`.
The `UserControl` would mostly have that toolbar and `GridView` (Devexpress).
I'm using WPF with MVVM and Caliburn.Micro framework for development.

The problem is that, that I need to c/p code of the `ToolBarControl` in the `XAML` and then in `ViewModel` to implement the properties.

I'm searching for a better way, and for now I guess it would be reflection.
Any advice would be helpful, code examples too.

Update #2

The controls who would be in the custom toolbar, would should be able to move selected row up or down, delete item, edit and create (last two should open a new window).
Let's say I have CustomersListViewModel, who in it's CustomersListView has the custom `ToolBarControl` and `GridControl`.
When I click add button, it should open me CustomersEditViewModel.
When I click delete, it should delete selected item in list.
When I click move up, it should move up selected row.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a datatemplate toolbarviemodel and toolbarview in your app.xaml and then use a contentcontrol to show the toolbar binding it to an instance of your toolbarviewmodel

app.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelToolBar}">
        <startViews:ViewToolBar />
    </DataTemplate>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

and in your usercontrol:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModelToolBar}"/>
```

and to execute your commands you could use a notify event with a tag or so as parameter to tell your usercontrol viewmodel wich operation should be performed.Means you bind your toolbar buttons to the notifycommand and use button name or tag as parameter.

ViewModelToolBar:

```
 public event EventHandler Notify;

    private void OnNotify(object sender)
    {
        Notify?.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
    }

    public ICommand NotifyCommand => new DelegateCommand<object>(OnNotify);
```

and in your usercontrol ViewModel:

```
 MyViewModelToolBar = new ViewModelToolBar();
 ViewModelToolBar.Notify += ViewModelToolBar_Notify;

  private void ViewModelToolBar_Notify(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (sender.ToString())
            {
                case "Case1":
                   "perform your operation"
                    break;
                case "Case2":
                   ...
                    break;
                case "Case3":
                   ...
                    break;
                              }
        }
```

Comment: How do I bind this to my `GridControl`.

Comment: The part with the switch statement should be in the viewmodel where you can edit the CustomersEditViewModel data

Comment: This means that in every `UserControl` who contains my custom toolbar I need to implement switch statement...
Doesn't it?

Comment: Do you create your CustomersEditViewModel instances in your CustomersListViewModel? Then you could create the ViewModelToolBarModel in CustomersListViewModel and pass it as parameter to your CustomersEditViewModel for example

Comment: Do you always use the same operations with same ViewModel types?

Comment: No I create it instances in MainViewModel.